# Calculation involving result of aggregate function, sort by that value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use percentile_disc to get median values grouped by username, make a calculation based on those median values, and then sort by the calculated number. Example code:

```
SELECT username, percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sharecount) as median_shares, friends
FROM posts
GROUP BY username, friends
```

I want to do this, but I don't know how to do it properly and this can't work because you can't use aliases as variables where I need to:

```
SELECT username, percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sharecount) as median_shares, friends, median_shares/friends as ratio
FROM posts
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY ratio
```

Sample data:

```
[{username = 'bob', sharecount = 99, fans = 50000},
{username = 'bob', sharecount = 52, fans = 50000},
{username = 'bob', sharecount = 21, fans = 50000},
{username = 'greg', sharecount = 33, fans = 10000},
{username = 'greg', sharecount = 77, fans = 10000}]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  What is the issue with your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT username,
       percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by sharecount) as median_shares,
       friends,
       (percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by sharecount) * 1.0 /
        friends) as ratio
FROM posts
GROUP BY username, friends
ORDER BY ratio;
```

If so, the issue is that you cannot re-use a column alias in the same `SELECT` where it is defined.  You need to repeat the expression (as above) or use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Okay so this is exactly what I want, and while it does run, ratio always come back at 0 for every row. As an example, one row comes back `{median_shares = 99, fans = 50000, ratio = 0}` Why is this?

Comment: @Max . . . Postgres does integer division of integers.  I get around this by multiplying by 1.0, but there are other methods as well.